# Calling bootstrap alerts on form error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I have the following HTML code for the alert div:

```
<div id="formAlert" class="alert">  
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>  
  <strong>Warning!</strong> Make sure all fields are filled and try again.  
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(){
  var x=document.forms['register']['username'].value;
  if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert('This is an alert')
    return false;
        var alertDialog = document.getElementByid("formAlert");
        alertDialog.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

The problem with the code is that the alert is showing prematurely, even before the code is called. I can tell the alert is called when the default JavaScript alert box pops up. Ideally, when `validateForm()` is called, I want the alert to show up. `validateForm()` is called when the form is submit.

**EDIT**: As requested, here is the code triggering the validateForm():

```
<form name="register" action="" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

Now that I've solved the issue of calling it, how do I hide the div until it's called by the JavaScript, as it's already showing before the code executes.

Comment: Since the Bootstrap library requires jQuery, why don't you use that throughout your code as well? Anyways, show the code where you're calling `valdateForm`. Note that code **after** a `return` statement doesn't execute

Comment: @Ian To be completely honest, I didn't bother learning much JavaScript, because this is the only JavaScript I'll ever need to add to the entire site. I'm just working off of the basics I've already learned a long time ago. About the return part, yeah, that would be part of the problem...

Comment: Well using your code, I couldn't get it to *not* work properly. But if it's any consolation, here's how I'd set it up: http://jsfiddle.net/VzVy6/1/

Comment: @Ian The only issue I see is, the message only appears once. If you close it and submit the form, it won't give the error again.

Comment: Ahh interesting, I'll look into that; sorry about that!

Comment: It seems that using the `data-dismiss` attribute completely removes the Alert. Instead, you could remove the attribute and manually hide/show the Alert, even with an animation. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/VzVy6/6/

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I'll take a look into it. The code is quite a bit different, but I should be able to just adapt it to my needs, as I mentioned before, limited JS knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, it's very different. It separates JavaScript from HTML, so that there's no inline script (generally a good practice). If it helps, I updated the fiddle and added comments to help explain: http://jsfiddle.net/VzVy6/8/ . Let me know if you need more help or more explanation. I'm just going to create an answer here, so comment there if you need more help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you reorganize your code, you can separate the JavaScript from the HTML completely and deal with events there. Here's how I'd set it up:

```
<div id="main_area" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 offset1">
        <div id="formAlert" class="alert hide">  
          <a class="close">×</a>  
          <strong>Warning!</strong> Make sure all fields are filled and try again.
        </div>

        <form name="register" action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Run this code only when the DOM (all elements) are ready

    $('form[name="register"]').on("submit", function (e) {
        // Find all <form>s with the name "register", and bind a "submit" event handler

        // Find the <input /> element with the name "username"
        var username = $(this).find('input[name="username"]');
        if ($.trim(username.val()) === "") {
            // If its value is empty
            e.preventDefault();    // Stop the form from submitting
            $("#formAlert").slideDown(400);    // Show the Alert
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();    // Not needed, just for demonstration
            $("#formAlert").slideUp(400, function () {    // Hide the Alert (if visible)
                alert("Would be submitting form");    // Not needed, just for demonstration
                username.val("");    // Not needed, just for demonstration
            });
        }
    });

    $(".alert").find(".close").on("click", function (e) {
        // Find all elements with the "alert" class, get all descendant elements with the class "close", and bind a "click" event handler
        e.stopPropagation();    // Don't allow the click to bubble up the DOM
        e.preventDefault();    // Don't let any default functionality occur (in case it's a link)
        $(this).closest(".alert").slideUp(400);    // Hide this specific Alert
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VzVy6/8/

The `data-dismiss` attribute on the `<a class="close">×</a>` actually removes the Alert when clicked, so you can't show it again later. So instead of using that attribute, you can do what you want by manually hiding/showing the specific Alert associated with the `class="close"` elements.

Comment: Now, this is a pretty simple question, but I may as well ask to make sure I get things right. I have like 10 fields that it needs to check, how could I easily do this with minimal code?

Comment: Why the alert message is not displaying in my case.?

Comment: Do I have to change something or add a library for this to work?

Comment: @Jen143Me Yes you need to include Bootstrap 2 if you want it to work in your own project. Any newer version of Bootstrap may need changes. The way to make the alert display is to click submit without typing anything in the textbox