# Required field only if condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, required

I have a form with, among other fields, a picture for the user to upload and a hidden field to hold ID. I need the picture to be required only if ID is empty, otherwise the user is editing, so there is already a picture in there.

Can it be done with HTML only? Maybe this could be done with javascript, but how to show this default popup (shown below) that appears when you just set `required`? I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449714/calling-bootstrap-alerts-on-form-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572882/how-to-show-validation-message-below-each-textbox-using-jquery) questions, but they don't provide the expected result.

Popup:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I just thought about this: make php check if ID is empty, if positive, echo `required` in picture, if negative, echo nothing.. hmm

Comment: I feel silly now.. but still curious about how to 'call' that popup/hint from js, if possible in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set that 'popup', you need to call [HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) on the element.

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
// check condition
foo.setCustomValidity("A custom message for the popup");
```

The code found [here](https://codepen.io/diegoleme/pen/surIK) helped me figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Simple:
Consider to use an array called "files" of your images ID´s:

```
var file = this.files[0];
var fileType = file["type"];
var ValidImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
if ($.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes) < 0) {
     // invalid condition goes here.
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you misunderstood my question.